# Как вывести количество одинаковых имен из MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

Есть база , в ней таблица со следующими колонками: id(id идет не по порядку, некоторые записи удаляю), name.

`$test = $c->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM`base`WHERE name = "Sony"');`

Так я получу общее количество сколько всего имен "Sony" в базе.

1. Sony
2. Sony
3. Sony
4. Samsung
5. Samsung
6. Apple

В данном случае я получу - Sony = 3.

Как мне составить запрос так, чтобы я получил сразу количество всех имен в базе? Sony = 3, Samsung = 2, Apple = 1.

Я знаю что нужно использовать GROUP BY, но я так и не понял как составить правильно запрос . Помогите пожалуйста!

`$test = $c->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, name FROM base GROUP BY name');`

`$test->execute();`

`$name=$test->fetchColumn();`

`echo "<th><button>name:</button><span style='color: #00ff00'>" . $site . "</span></th>";`

Получается Sony: 3. Выводит только количество 1 имени.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, name FROM base GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: выводит только количество  1 имени

Comment: $test = $c->prepare()  - что делает этот метод? подготавливает запрос? выполняет? как вы получаете сами данные в скрипте php?

Comment: Добавил код в вопросе, как получаю данные.

Comment: $name=$test->fetchColumn();  здесь вы выбираете только ПЕРВЫЙ результат запроса. Ознакомьтесь с документацией своего фреймворка.

Comment: fetchColumn() получаю сколько всего одинаковых имен  fetchColumn(1) получаю само имя

Comment: Получается мне надо заменить fetchColumn() но на что ?

Comment: Если регулярка - цикл while

Comment: Что бы проверить, работает запрос или нет, используйте phpmyadmin или другие клиенты для работы с бд